# MySQL: очередной вопрос про сортировку по двум полям

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица:

```
| id | name | 
+----+------+
|  1 | john | 
|  2 | alex | 
|  4 | ivan | 
|  5 | ivan | 
|  6 | alex | 
|  8 | john |
```

Нужно отсортировать по id, но так, чтобы имена были не перемешаны, а сгруппированы:

```
| id | name | 
+----+------+
|  1 | john | 
|  8 | john | 
|  2 | alex | 
|  6 | alex | 
|  4 | ivan | 
|  5 | ivan |
```

То есть если у наименьшего id = 1 имя john, то все остальные записи с именем john должны идти следом отсортированные по id. Как это можно сделать?

UPDATE: MySQL 5.1

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Приведите, пожалуйста, запрос, которым вы пытались решить эту задачу.

Comment: @Softimage Читайте внимательнее: *если у наименьшего id = 1 имя john, то все остальные записи с именем john должны идти следом отсортированные по id*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких диких, как я - по старинке

```
select t.id, t.name 
  from  t 
     join 
       (select min(id) orderid, name from t group by name) as o 
     on t.name = o.name 
  order by orderid, t.id
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/871426/24)

Comment: Почему-то на демке работает правильно, а на моей системе - нет. Получается такой вывод по id: 1, 8, 6, 2, 5, 4... То есть в второго и последующих имён сортировка неверная. Буду разбираться...

Comment: проверьте, что alex написан одинаково - можно для начала выполнить подзапрос `select min(id) orderid, name from t group by name` и посмотреть, как имена сгруппировались и почему - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/871426/17

Comment: Ну наверное сортировать всё же нужно по двум полям: `order by o.orderid, t.id`, а без `t.id` сортировки внутри группы одинаковых имён же не будет, а будет как попало.

Comment: @splash58, да, это первое что я проверил - вложенный запрос выдаёт одинаковые результаты. Кстати, и при использовании "order by orderid desc" получается не тот результат, которого хотелось бы ожидать. Пока до конца не прочувствовал запрос...

Comment: @CrazyElf вероятно, да, надо добавить, а то будет не то, что автор хотел

Comment: @CrazyElf, всё верно, просто добавить сортировку, что-то затупил.
Ну и для обратной сортировки меняем min на max, всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT id, name, MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name) min_id
    FROM source_table
)
SELECT id, name
FROM cte
ORDER BY min_id, id
```

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное, ответ правильный и хороший, но не работает на моей версии mysql (5.1). Моя ошибка, нужно было указать в условии. А начиная с какой версии работает этот вариант?

Comment: @Kverty CTE и оконные функции реализованы в MySQL начиная с версии 8, в mariaDB с 10.2, PS. 5.1 - это даже не седая древность, это уже прям археология какая-то. Задумайтесь всё же об обновлении.